# A variable is defined in makefile but Make ignores it. Why?

Tags: makefile

From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html#Target_002dspecific):

> There is one more special feature of target-specific variables: when you define a target-specific variable that variable value is also in effect for all prerequisites of this target, and all their prerequisites, etc. (unless those prerequisites override that variable with their own target-specific variable value).

So, given a makefile:

```make
$(shell rm -rf x D)
$(shell mkdir D)
$(shell touch D/x)

VPATH = D

all: x ;

x ::
    @echo 'foo is: $(foo)'

.SILENT : D/x

all : foo = bar
```

Running, I get:

```console
foo is:
```

And I thought, that I defined above: `foo = bar`!

Or, did I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you have a mix with [VPATH](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#General-Search), [Double-Colon Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Double_002dColon), [Target-specific Variable Values](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific) and [Special Built-in Target Names](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Special-Targets).

Your `Makefile` can be interpreted as:

- `all` is the first target
- `all` have one prerequisite: `x`
- As `VPATH` is `D`, `all` have also an **indirect** prerequisite: `D/x`
- The `D/x` target is silent
- `all` and all these prerequisites have a target specific variable `foo` equal to `bar`

It seems that the **indirect** prerequisite `D/x` is not taken into account for the target specific thing.

---

***Interresting test:*** Add `x : foo = bar` at the end of your `Makefile` and the `make`process will be stuck...

---

**Workarounds**:

1. Remove the `.SILENT` line (I found this after some tests, it also fix the issue above...)
2. Add `D/x : foo = bar` at the end of your `Makefile` to explicitely add the `foo` variable for the `D/x`target