# Make freezes when parsing this makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

With credit to [jml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32071583/5184385), here is a makefile that will run forever:

```make
# We want to create a directory 'D'. Therefore, remove a "regular" file 'D'.
$(shell rm -rf D)
# 'x' will not exist, So Make may "search" for it in the VPATH directory
$(shell rm -rf x)
$(shell mkdir D)
# Finally, create 'D/x', that - hopefully - Make will "associate" with 'x'.
$(shell touch D/x)

VPATH = D

# 'x' is a target, with some ( - could be any! - ) recipe to execute!
x :: ; : blah blah

.SILENT : D/x

# A target-specific assignment, for target 'x'
x: foo =
```

Running, you will get a freezing process that will never finish, unless, abruptly aborted by a fatal signal.

Why?

Comment: Good catch. Not sure what's going on but make is definitely getting stuck in some sort of loop. I think it probably corrupts memory internally at some point when parsing/handling this. It happens with 3.81, 3.82, 4.0 and 4.1 too.